# Python regex causing list index out of range error

Tags: python, regex

Trying to extract just the email address from this format:

`John Smith <jsmith@email.com>`

I have tried both of the following and it results in the same error:

`IndexError: list index out of range`

```
email_address = re.findall('(?<=\<)\w+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-z]+(?=\>)', sender)[0]

email_address = re.findall('<([^>])>', sender)[0]
```

Rest of code:

```
import webapp2
import logging
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import mail_handlers
from google.appengine.api import mail
import os
from main import WorkRequest
import re


class IncomingMailHandler(mail_handlers.InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):
        (encoding, payload) = list(message.bodies(content_type='text/plain'))[0]
        body_text = payload.decode()
        logging.info('Received email message from %s, subject "%s": %s' %
                     (message.sender, message.subject, body_text))

        logging.info (message.sender)
        logging.info(message.subject)
        logging.info(body_text)


        sender = str(message.sender)

        email_address = re.findall('<([^>])>', sender)[0]

        wr = WorkRequest()

        wr.email = email_address
        wr.userId = None
        wr.title = message.subject
        wr.content = body_text
        wr.status = "OPEN"
        wr.submission_type = "EMAIL"
        wr.assigned_to = "UNASSIGNED"
        wr.put()

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/_ah/mail/.+', IncomingMailHandler)],debug=True)
```

Can anyone please help? I am using Google App Engine with Python if that matters.

Comment: can you do `print(sender)` and add the output to your question?

Comment: the regex looks good, it gets `jsmith@email.com` out of `"John Smith <jsmith@email.com>"`

Comment: The first regex works for me (assuming sender is `John Smith <jsmith@email.com>`).  The second one works if you add a plus sign after the closing square bracket.

Answer (score 1):

In my case first regex works fine:

```
>>> sender = 'John Smith <jsmith@email.com>'
>>> email_address = re.findall('(?<=\<)\w+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-z]+(?=\>)', 
        sender)[0]
>>> email_address
'jsmith@email.com'
```

Second is invalid because you get empty list as a result, so you can't get item at index 0:

```
email_address = re.findall('<([^>])>', sender)
>>> email_address
[]
```

You can check your regex at http://rubular.com/
It's free and easy to use.

[image: invalid]

[image: valid]